# What is the best driver/stack to use with a SICK LMS-1xx?

Tags: ros, sicklms, laserscanner, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the [LMS1xx](http://wiki.ros.org/LMS1xx) package, but, according to the wiki page, it is only tested/good for groovy, despite the fact that there is a `ros-hydro-lms1xx` package available for installation.  I tried installing `ros-hydro-lms1xx` and running the `LMS1xx.launch` script, but it fails to find the `LMS1xx_node` in the `LMS1xx` package, because `LMS1xx` is spelled `lms1xx` in the `.deb` file.

It's relatively trivial to fix that, or even to download and recompile the source code from github, but I wonder if I'm heading down an unmaintained path.

So I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask what folks are using nowadays in the Hydro era (which is where I live), or perhaps in the Indigo era, which is arguably, where I should live.

--wpd

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192205/what-is-the-best-driver/stack-to-use-with-a-sick-lms-1xx?/) by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 249 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package you refer to is released into Groovy, Hydro and Indigo as [lms1xx](http://wiki.ros.org/lms1xx). They did a release into Indigo fairly recently, so it looks like it's actively maintained.

If the launch file doesn't work, you should probably file that as a bug on github, or submit a pull request.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0